# On SLES8, after the second JnextPlan, an agent does not link in Workload Scheduler

Tags: workload-scheduler

I’m having a problem with an agent on SLES8 with the Workload Scheduler. The first **JnextPlan** works fine, but the second fails, with **conman** giving an error. How can I do?

Comment: Please add the error message which are you receiving to your question. Otherwise, it's unclear whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the library *ligcc_s.so.1* is missing on the agent workstation. This is a library and usually it should be located in */lib*. Try to look for it in other directories such as */usr/lib*. When you have located it, make a soft link to it from the */lib* directory and rerun **JnextPlan**. 
If you can’t locate it in your computer, contact the IBM Software Support.